# How to make correct my azure deployment issue by rearranging my azure-pipelines.yml?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to establish a pipeline by using azure cloud and devops. But I got an error below while deploying from succeeded building. How can I solve this issue?

I read an article it is awesome "http://www.alessandromoura.com.br/2020/04/23/azure-devops-publish-and-download-artifacts/"

I applied your rule sets but I got error always below :

Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.zip
Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.

azure-pipelines.yml :

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'xxxxx'
  imageRepository: 'xxxhelloaspnetcore'
  containerRegistry: 'xxxcontainer01.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - download: none
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
      inputs:
        patterns: '**/*.zip'
        path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Degug parameters'
      inputs:
        targetType: Inline
        script: |
            Write-Host "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
            Write-Host "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
            Write-Host "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"
            Write-Host "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
            Write-Host "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"
```

Comment: Where are you publishing a pipeline artifact? You can't download a pipeline artifact unless you publish one first. The blog post is wrong or offering incomplete information. Look at the official documentation.

Comment: I have no idea about that. So I can not answer "Where are you publishing a pipeline artifact?" how can I write correct yaml? Or whatelse.Thak you.

Comment: Start by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline creates and pushes image to container registry so you don't have there pipeline artifacts. This is why `DownloadPipelineArtifact` throws error.

`DownloadPipelineArtifact` makes sens only if you use `PublishPipelineArtifact` before. This [doc - Publish and download artifacts in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) describe it very well.

There is also a way to download artifacts from another pipeline - but it requires to use [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines), but you don't have defined pipeline resource in your pipeline.

So all works as expected. Can you explain what actually do you want to download and what achieve by that?